# How can show a specific value in `select_tag`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my select tag that I would change for specific values:

```
<div class="select_field">
      <%= select_tag 
      "quote[service_id]",options_for_select(AvailableService.all.map { |u|   
       [u.service_type.titleize+" - "+ (u.service_name == "housekeeping" ? 
       "House cleaning" : u.service_name), u.id] }), { prompt: "Select   
       Service", required: true } %>
     </div>
```

Comment: Hello William, you are on english version of stackoverflow, you need to ask in english, or go to es.stackoverflow to go there with spanish.

Comment: Write the detail of the question in the text, not in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collection_select`

```
    <%= collection_select :service_id, AvailableService.where(service_type:"cleaning"), 
                    :id, :service_name, {}, {prompt:"Select Service", required: true} %>
```